# Why does slick slider not return errors while not providing any functionality?

Tags: jquery, slick.js

I am trying to implement slick slider into my application, but it has not effect at all. There is no error returned in the console and everything looks OK to me.

```html
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.min.css" />
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="variants" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #CDCDCD;width:192px; height:223px;float:left;">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="variants" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #CDCDCD;width:192px; height:223px;float:left;">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="variants" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #CDCDCD;width:192px; height:223px;float:left;">
        test
      </div>
      <div class="variants" style="cursor:pointer;border:1px solid #CDCDCD;width:192px; height:223px;float:left;">
        test
      </div>
      
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
     
      <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('.variants').slick({
            infinite: true,
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          });
        });
      </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I need to keep 4.01 in place and hope this is not the issue. All files are loaded OK. Why is the slider not showing?

Comment: Are you sure there's no errors? You're trying to call `slick()` *before* you've added the reference to `slick.min.js` to the page...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Yes, there is no error. Good point about calling slick, changed it butt still no erorr and no effect.

Comment: Load jQuery with  jquery-migrate and retry.

Comment: jQuery-Migrate is loaded just before slick.js

Comment: Also load jQuery main version  before  jquery-migrate.

Comment: Loaded within the header.

Comment: You need to put all .variants div elements inside a parent div and then pass that parent class or ID in slick method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you have fixed the order of scripts in your question the issue is due to how you instantiate the `slick()` slider. You're calling it on the elements to slide instead of on a single containing element. Try this instead:

```js
$('.variants-container').slick({
  infinite: true,
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 3
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #CCC;
}

.variants {
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #CDCDCD;
  width: 192px;
  height: 223px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="variants-container">
  <div class="variants">test</div>
  <div class="variants">test</div>
  <div class="variants">test</div>
  <div class="variants">test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great! That is one big step further, last thing missing to work are the arrows to access the other elments. They do not show up in the example and also not in my implementation. I do also get the error: Access to font at '/app_global/slick/fonts/slick.ttf' from origin 'server' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: The arrows are there, they were just not visible before because the background was white. See my updated answer. With regard to the CORS issue, I've not seen that before on a local request. I'd suggest starting a new question for it.

Comment: Right, in your answer they are there now. In my case the arrows do not show up, neither the dots on the bottom to indicate more results. Guess this is another question. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad to help. I'd suggest checking out the references to the CSS files for the slick slider and ensuring they're loading correctly.